# Are "class prototypes" possible in C++?

Tags: c++, class, heap, priority-queue, function-prototypes

I'm trying to implement a priority queue (as a heap of pointers) in C++. This may or may not be bad design, but I made a class PriorityQueue (which would encompass the entire heap) and another class Node for each node in the heap. It looks something like this:

```
class PriorityQueue {
    public:
        Node* root;

        void insert(Node* n) {
            n->ancestor = this;
            root->insert(n);
        }
}

class Node {
     public:
         PriorityQueue* ancestor;
         Node* parent, left, right;

         void insert(Node* n) { /* really long insert algorithm */ }
}
```

These classes reference each other, so I need some kind of prototype. I tried adding `class PriorityQueue;` and `class Node;` at the beginning, but I get an error for invalid use of incomplete type. Is it possible to do this the way I want to, or should I change my design entirely?

Comment: Are you looking for a "[friend](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)"?

Comment: Make `Node` an inner class.

Answer (score 3):

Let us forget the term *prototype*, and focus on *forward declaration* and *definition*.

A forward declaration tells the compiler that there exists a class (or struct or union) and the name of the class.  Nothing more.  This is usually used in header file to resolve pointer and references for parameters and return types.

The compiler needs a full *definition* in order to resolve access to stuff in the structure.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with "invalid use of incomplete type" comes because of the way that you define the `insert` method in the `PriorityQueue` class. All you need to do in order to fix this is to move the implementation to a location after the declaration of the `Node`, like this:

```
class Node; // <<== I assume that you already have this
class PriorityQueue {
    public:
        Node* root;
        // At this point, the definition of Node is incomplete.
        // You can declare pointers or references of type Node,
        // but you cannot call its member functions, because the compiler
        // does not know what functions are available for the Node.
        void insert(Node* n);
}; // <<== Do not forget semicolons
class Node {
     public:
         PriorityQueue* ancestor;
         Node* parent, left, right;
         void insert(Node* n);
}; // <<== Do not forget semicolons
// At this point, C++ compiler knows what functions the Node has,
// so it lets you make calls of member functions.
void PriorityQueue::insert(Node* n) {
    n->ancestor = this;
    root->insert(n);
}
void Node::insert(Node* n) {
    /* really long insert algorithm */
}
```